# Get settings of all lists and libraries in a SharePoint Site Collection with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Yes, by all settings I mean, all settings... from versioning to RSS Settings and everything in Advanced settings. Can this be done?

Is there any way I can loop through all the settings without hard coding the type of setting?

Instead of looping settings by name, can I do it by calling some array?

```
  $Columns = "ListURL" + ";" + "ContentTypesEnabled" + ";" + "EnableVersioning"
       $logFile = "E:\PowerShell\site.csv" # Log Location
     $Columns | out-file -filepath $logfile -Force

$url= "MyURL";
    $web = Get-SPWeb($url)

    #$url = $web.Url
    Write-Output "Web Url: $url"
   # Write-Host "ContentTypesEnabled", "EnableVersioning";


   # $listName = $web.Lists["CheckList"]
   foreach($listName in $web.Lists)
   {
   if($listName.Hidden -ne 1)
   {
    $output = $listName.DefaultViewUrl+ ";" + $listName.ContentTypesEnabled + ";" + $listName.EnableVersioning +";" + $listName.

    $output | out-file -filepath $logfile -Append
   # $output | Format-Table -Property ListURL,ContentTypesEnabled,EnableVersioning
    }
```